# Return from mysqli_query() into array

Tags: php, arrays, error-handling, mysqli

I'm working on a project where I have a database class with some functions that may be used throughout the project.  One of the functions basically executes a query and returns anything that may be a result of that query.

I want to put that return value into an array.  This is because I have an error function called within the query function and want to return that as well.  This is my query function:

```
//Execute query
function executeQuery($payload, $database){

    //Create database connection
    $con = connectDB($database);

    //execute query
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $payload);

    //Check for error
    $error = sqlErrorHandling($con);

    //Create return array
    $returnArray = array($error, $result);

    //Return result
    return $returnArray;    

}
```

I know that the `sqlErrorHandling()` function works and my `connectDB()` function works, but this function gives me the error: `Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array`

I'm assuming that due to my putting `$result` in an array.  Is there any way to do this?

This is the code that's giving me the error:

```
$result = executeQuery($databaseQuery, null);

        //Create local variables based off array
        list ($error, $result) = $result;
```

**NOTE:**
I'm **NOT** trying to get the value of the rows in with this bit of code.  It may very well be used to do so, but this is supposed to be a **generic** function to execute a query and then allow multiple things to be done with that query.  For instance using it in `mysqli_num_rows` and such like that.

Comment: Where exactly does that error occur, i.e. what line?

Comment: Where I try to create a variable from the array (using list):
 `$result = executeQuery($databaseQuery, null);
 
        //Create local variables based off array
        list ($error, $result) = $result;`

Comment: My bad I meant to do a line break

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp

Comment: @Mr.Monshaw  That won't work because the result of the query will be used for multiple things such as `mysqli_num_rows`

Comment: You're going to have to first get all the results and then use them.. you cant use the object returned from the query like you are trying

Comment: Ok thanks for that.  I understand that part.

Comment: Why the down vote?  Is it not a valid question?

Comment: @Mr.Monshaw  No worries.  The question is somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is all wrong.

First, this function should throw an **exception** in case of error, not return it
Next, you should connect **once**, not every time you run a query! And pass connection resource into function.

This is how it should be

```
function executeQuery($con, $query){

    //execute query
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        throw new Exception($con->error);
    }

    //Return result
    return $result;
}
$result = executeQuery($con, $databaseQuery);
```

this way you will have your result along with **proper** error reporting.

Comment: I see many reasons for a function.  Prevents recursive code.  I'm working on a rest api and I see no reason in having to type in `mysqli_query` a bunch of times when I can save a lot of time by just calling one line of code instead of multiple lines.

Comment: And that may work but I want to handle my errors since it is an api.  Not just throw an exception.

Comment: Exceptions are the best way to handle errors, mind you. Though I doubt you going to really *handle* them.

Comment: This is an api that is going to be open source.  If the person who uses the api want's to do something with their error than I want to let them do that.  That's why I wanted to return the error as well.  Not only that but the `$error` was supposed to be a the error number so I could pass that back to ajax and show a specialized message based of the error number.

Comment: Oh, exception is the only way then. This is the standard way "to do something with the error". The only acceptable way

Comment: No, you don't need no specialized message based of the error number. But a generalized error message along with HTTP status 500. Please, please, please, learn general and web programming basics.